# THREE.js: Change image of only one face in Cubemap?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to show a panorama using cubemaps where first 6 low quality images are loaded and displayed on the cubemap. This is easily done using

```
var urls = [
'path/to/low-q-pos-x.png',
'path/to/low-q-neg-x.png',
'path/to/low-q-pos-y.png',
'path/to/low-q-neg-y.png',
'path/to/low-q-pos-z.png',
'path/to/low-q-neg-z.png' 
],

cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
```

Next, the higher quality 6 images are loaded.
What I'm trying to do here is that as soon as a higher quality image is loaded, it should replace the lower quality image, and so the higher quality images are applied one by one. Using `loadTextureCube` everytime is an option, but is there a more direct way to replace cube faces?

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your skybox images.

Load a new `CubeTexture`.

```
var newTexture = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls, onLoadCallback );
```

Then, in your callback, assign your skybox the new texture.

```
var oldTexture = skybox.material.uniforms.tCube.value;

skybox.material.uniforms.tCube.value = null;
oldTexture.dispose(); // important!

skybox.material.uniforms.tCube.value = newTexture;
```

Type `renderer.info` into the console to make sure your old textures are being disposed of properly.

three.js r.76

Comment: So, I'll have to do this 6 times for each change in high quality image?

Comment: Update all 6 at once, as proposed.

Comment: I think my question may not be very clear. I am already updating all 6 images at once currently. Since the 6 face images take some time to load on slow networks, it's possible that 5 faces are already loaded and just one is taking time to load. So, why wait for the last one, when I can apply the 5 high quality faces immediately and apply the last one after it's loaded.

Comment: Something similar to what I want can be seen here: http://krpano.com/tours/paris/
A blurry skybox is displayed initially, and one by one sharper patches are applied. Might have to throttle the internet speed to low speeds to see the effect...

Comment: That is a reasonable request. It does not seem to be possible as the library is currently written, however. But perhaps you can, instead, have 6 planes each with its own texture -- or `BoxGeometry` with `MultiMaterial`:  http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama.html